# How to set the values of different channels in a numpy array to zero based on index values from another array without using loops?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy array "arr" and an array of indices "ind":

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(255, size=(100,64,64,16))

ind = np.random.randint(16, size=(100,2))
```

In `arr`, the last dimension represents channels while the first dimension represents number of samples. In `ind`, each row represents the two random channel indices corresponding to every sample in `arr`. I wish to make the values of entire `64 x 64` channel equal to `0` for every sample in `arr` corresponding to channel index in `ind`, **without using any loop**. How can this be achieved?

I have tried using:

```
arr[:,:,:,ind] = 0
```

I thought that indices would be broadcasted as per the sample, but instead entire array becomes `0`. Using loops is quite time consuming and inefficient. I also wanted to use `np.where`,  but I am not sure what condition to use to access the indices of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can the same command be somehow modified to perform other operations like divide all the corresponding values by 2 or square the corresponding values, and so on.

Comment: Yes, in some sense. I think your best bet is to first `np.take_along_axis` using the same parameters (except 0), then modify them, and call `np.put_along_axis` using the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis) for this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(255, size=(100,64,64,16))
ind = np.random.randint(16, size=(100,2))

np.put_along_axis(arr, ind[:, None, None, :], 0, axis=3)
```